# SQL Order by alphanumerical

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query

```
SELECT PartNumber   
FROM [devbivarcom].[Products].[Products]   
ORDER BY PartNumber ASC
```

I get..

```
LC-4.12
LC-4.25
LC-4.5
LC-4.975
LC-40.0
LC-48.0
LC-5.0
LC-5.5
LC-5.75
```

Is there any way I can make it alphanumerical or recognize decimals?

So it s like...

```
LC-4.12
LC-4.25
LC-4.5
LC-4.975
LC-5.0
LC-5.5
LC-5.75
LC-40.0
LC-48.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get your desired order, it isn't alphabetical nor is it ordered by the numerical value

Comment: @Lamak, I would say the additional `48.0` was just a typo.

Comment: @bluefeet @michael you guys are most likely right, didn't realize the duplicated `48.0`

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Update your question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order by the numeric portion only you can use the `STUFF()` function:

```
ORDER BY CAST(STUFF(col1,1,3,'')AS FLOAT)
```

Demo: [SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd31/4/0)

Comment: I get SUBSTR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user3241586 Sorry, question was tagged MySQL initially, updated.

Comment: Didn't see the first tag. Seems to work great now

Comment: @user3241586 yeah in MySQL you can use only 2 arguments to take all characters from a specified point to the end of the string, in SQL Server you have to specify the ending point in the 3rd argument of `SUBSTRING()`, so `STUFF()` is a better function to use.

Comment: thanks so much but i get the Error converting data type nvarchar to float.  I am using nvarchar and when I change int to nvarchar i get this weird sorting

Comment: @user3241586 then you have some data that doesn't follow the format showed in your sample data. You need to first add `STUFF(col1,1,3,'')` to your `SELECT` and inspect the results, look for values that aren't numbers

Comment: @user3241586 You could also use `WHERE ISNUMERIC(STUFF(col1,1,3,'')) = 0` to find offending lines.

Comment: Doesn't work Goat CO some of the partnumers have spaces and such

Comment: @user3241586 Yeah we can't assess for situations not presented in the question.  You'll have to use a `CASE` statement to handle the variations. If you add them to the question I can show you how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If part number is broken down by prefix that is a "category", separate by "-", then suggest something to split partnumber into the "category" and the number:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Partnumber, 1, charindex("-",Partnumber)-1), cast(substring(Partnumber, charindex("-",Partnumberd)+1) as float)
```